# asynchronous code with modalbox jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm opening a jQuery modal box like this:

```
jQuery ("myDialog").dialog ({
  open: function () {
     jQuery(this).load('loadDataFromServer.htm');
  }
});
```

the complicated part is that `loadDataFromServer.htm` has some ajax calls inside it as well. So, the dialog box opens up every time, however, the content inside the dialog box (coming from `loadDataFromServer.htm`) shows up only intermittently.

I suspect that this is because of the asynchronous nature of the ajax calls. Is there a best practice to manage this well?

Comment: you want to open dialog only after content loaded ? why not do `load` and only than `open` in load's callback ?

Comment: You mean do this? `jQuery("#mydialog").load('loadDataFromServer.htm').dialog({modal:true});` This also works intermittently, again since I guess because `loadDataFromServer.htm` has ajax calls inside of it

Comment: what i can suggest not to use ajax call inside loaded htm, because you will get very hard to maintanance code, or at least load content to opacity 0 div and make dialog after load